# How to replicate case comment functionality in custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, case

In a custom object i have a related list called comments. I have to show time at which comment is created and want to show that time stamp next to comment as it was shown in case comment. how can i achieve this?

i'm newbie to salesforce, please help me to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to the Salesforce StackExchange and welcome to Salesforce! I tried to be as thorough as possible in the answer below to help you along. Post more questions here if you run into other problems and I am sure others will continue to help. Enjoy the platform and good luck!

Comment: thank you for your support.... i'll use this platform to improve my knowledge @JesseAltman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are looking to replicate the functionality below:

[image: Case Comments]

Unfortunately, you won't be able to replicate anything exactly like this with a normal related list on a custom object. You will need to customize your `Comment__c` object's related list on the parent object. You can do this through the normal `Setup > Build > Create > Objects` flow or on the parent object's detail page in the top left hand corner with `Edit Layout`

[image: Edit Layout]

Once on the layout screen, navigate down to the [related list to customize it](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizing_related_lists.htm&language=en_US) and add some of [Salesforce's system fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm). Specifically, you are interested in the `Created By` and `Created Date` fields.

[image: Comments Related List]

Once you set that, your related list should have all of the information you are looking for:

[image]

As I mentioned before, this is a slightly different format than the `Case Comment` but it has all of the same information.